# Are nouns derived from verbs (e.g. devoir) always masculine?

Tags: genre, noms

I assume that le devoir is derived from the verb devoir, as opposed to the other way around. Are there many other nouns derived from verbs, such that the noun is identical to the verb? Are these nouns always masculine?

Comment: Many nouns converted from verbs are not masculine. For example, *arrivée, saisie, mise, tenue, crainte* are all feminine nouns derived from verbs past participle while *grimpe, triche* and many others are converted from present singular. Delphine Tribout's phd [dissertation](https://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-01577528/document) contains a thorough discussion of French verb converts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of such nouns:

- To designate a period of time when people do a specific action in a day-to-day schedule (lever, déjeuner...)
- To designate a specific notion, often (but not only) in philosophy, it can happen that a verb is directly used as a noun (l'être et le paraître, le savoir-faire, un avoir)
- To designate a specific action (un lancer)
- Some nouns are even perfect homonyms of verbs without a clear link between the two of them. Either one derived from the other a very long time ago or they just ended up being homonyms by the random of linguistic evolution (un boucher: a butcher, boucher: to clog)

As far as I know all these nouns are masculine, but I suspect you may find words of the last category that are feminine.

Comment: There is absolutely no link between the noun *boucher*, the man who was originally selling goat (*bouc*) flesh and the verb *boucher* which is related to *bouchon* (cork) and *bois/bosquet* (woods/bush).

Comment: No link, but it is still a perfect homonym. I edit my answer to make that clearer.

Comment: Merci. C'est très utile.

Comment: According to [TLFi](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/boucher#art13721), BOUCHER is meant to come from BOUC: *Dér. de bouc; suff. -ier (réduit à -er parce que précédé d'une palatale); le boucher étant à l'origine chargé d'abattre des boucs.*

Answer (score 2):

Your question is interesting, because I think the answer has to be precise:

The derivation of a verb to a noun car be either feminine or masculine when it is associated with a suffix: **la** dorure (from *dorer*), **le** garage (from *garer*), **la** parure (from *parer*), **la** moulure (from *mouler*), **le** codage (from *coder*).

But when the process consists of making the noun from the verb as it is, then the noun is **always** masculine:
*le coucher, le manger, le vouloir, le déjeûner, le dîner, le souper...*

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are many nouns derived from verbs :

```
Le bon vouloir
Le coucher
Le déjeuner / le dîner / le souper
Le savoir
```

etc.

This pages affirms that infinitive verbs used as nouns are neither masculine nor feminine but neutral : http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/462.html 
I don't know if that can be trusted, but at least that sounds right.

Comment: But because there is no neutral in French, this neutral has all the appearance of masculine, i.e. articles and adjectives used with an infinitive can't be but masculine.

Comment: There is no such thing as "neutral" in French grammar, the notion just doesn't exist.

Comment: Doesn't exist or just takes exactly the same form as masculine, so that we forgot it exists (or used to exist) ? see  http://latlntic.unige.ch/grammaticalite/?page_id=1554

Comment: It certainly used to exist, but that's not the case since quite a long time now. Par ailleurs ce lien est très intéressant, merci de l'avoir partagé !

Comment: There is a difference between *default gender* which is necessary in all languages featuring gender on nouns for coordination of nouns of different gender, and *neutral gender* which is the term used for the third gender of systems with masculine and feminine. *Masculine* and *feminine* are the traditional terms for gender systems where most male animates share a gender and most female animate share another.